# I can't find the partial sum

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I can't figure out the way to find the sum of the series $ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{ 2^n + 3^n}{6^n}$, I know it is through partial sums and that it is $\frac{3}{2}$ but I can't get them right.

Comment: Hint:  split it into two sums.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{ 2^n + 3^n}{6^n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{ 1 }{3}\right)^n+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{ 1 }{2}\right)^n$$
then use the geometric series.

Answer (score 0):

Split the sum in two, and remember that
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n=\frac x{1-x}\quad\text{for all } x\:\text{ such that }\:|x|<1.$$